# Cats Seq[Xor[A,B]] => Xor[A, Seq[B]]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a sequence of Errors or Views (`Seq[Xor[Error,View]]`)

I want to map this to an Xor of the first error (if any) or a Sequence of Views
(`Xor[Error, Seq[View]]`) or possibly simply (`Xor[Seq[Error],Seq[View]`)

How can I do this?

Comment: The function name for that type of method is 'sequence' which is a special case of a 'traversal'. 

You something that will provide an impicit conversion of Xor to a Traverse I believe.
https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sequenceU` provided by the `bitraverse` syntax, similar to as you would do with scalaz. It doesn't seem like the proper type classes exist for `Seq` though, but you can use `List`.

```
import cats._, data._, implicits._, syntax.bitraverse._

case class Error(msg: String)

case class View(content: String)

val errors: List[Xor[Error, View]] = List(
  Xor.Right(View("abc")), Xor.Left(Error("error!")), 
  Xor.Right(View("xyz"))
)

val successes: List[Xor[Error, View]] = List(
  Xor.Right(View("abc")),
  Xor.Right(View("xyz"))
)

scala> errors.sequenceU
res1: cats.data.Xor[Error,List[View]] = Left(Error(error!))

scala> successes.sequenceU
res2: cats.data.Xor[Error,List[View]] = Right(List(View(abc), View(xyz)))
```

Answer (score 4):

In the most recent version of Cats `Xor` is removed and now the standard Scala `Either` data type is used.

Michael Zajac showed correctly that you can use `sequence` or `sequenceU` (which is actually defined on `Traverse` not `Bitraverse`) to get an `Either[Error, List[View]]`.

```
import cats.implicits._

val xs: List[Either[Error, View]] = ???

val errorOrViews: Either[Error, List[View]] = xs.sequenceU
```

*You might want to look at `traverse` (which is like a `map` and a `sequence`), which you can use most of the time instead of `sequence`.*

If you want all failing errors, you cannot use `Either`, but you can use `Validated` (or `ValidatedNel`, which is just a type alias for `Validated[NonEmptyList[A], B]`.

```
import cats.data.{NonEmptyList, ValidatedNel}

val errorsOrViews: ValidatedNel[Error, List[View]] = xs.traverseU(_.toValidatedNel)

val errorsOrViews2: Either[NonEmptyList[Error], List[View]] = errorsOrViews.toEither
```

You could also get the errors *and* the views by using `MonadCombine.separate` :

```
val errorsAndViews: (List[Error], List[View]) = xs.separate
```

You can find more examples and information on [`Either`](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/either.html) and [`Validated`](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) on the Cats website.

Comment: an update for current cats version: `xs.sequenceU` is currently just `xs.sequence`; `trverseU` is just `traverse`